# Convert Future to Stream: Future.asStream() vs Stream.fromFeature(...)

Tags: flutter, dart

Are there any differences between obtaining a stream using [`Future.asStream`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future/asStream.html) and [`Stream.fromFeature`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/Stream.fromFuture.html)?

Any pros or cons to using one over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually is exactly the same. I just checked the future implementation and the Future.asStream uses Stream.fromFeature:

```
Stream<T> asStream() => new Stream<T>.fromFuture(this);
```

You can check it here https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart.

Hope it helps!